# Android java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made

Tags: android, android-fonts

I am getting the following exception when trying to set a custom font to a button: `java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made` 
I already looked at similar questions but none of their solutions worked.

My font is inside src/main and the file structure seems to be fine.

Here is the file structure:

[image]

And here is the code:

```
private void generateButtonListener(final Button btn,final String inputText) {

    btn.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "rb.ttf"));

    btn.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view1) {
            getCurrentInputConnection().commitText(inputText,1);
        }

    });


}
```

Not sure if it matters but I am making a custom keyboard app so I am setting this listener on buttons in the `onCreateInputView` method. Like this:

```
   @Override
public View onCreateInputView() {

    LayoutInflater lInflate = getLayoutInflater();
    Resources res = getResources();
    LinearLayout inputView = (LinearLayout) lInflate.inflate(R.layout.copypasta, null);
    Button tab_navySeal = (Button) inputView.findViewById(R.id.tab_navySeal);
  Button nSeal_1 = (Button) btnset_navyseal.findViewById(R.id.nSeal_1);
        generateButtonListener(nSeal_1, res.getString(R.string.NStxt));
```

etc...

I seem to be following all the rules for fonts, what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you use the fonts as a library or

`btn.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "rb.ttf"));`

`rb.ttf`is the worng path? try`fonts/rb.ttf`